# How to hit the GET APIs in the MS graph for messages, contacts, calendar?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to hit the MS Graph APIs, to GET messages, contacts etc

1. Created a free office365 account through "office.com/" and created an app on http://dev.office.com/app-registration and logged in using the office365 credentials
2. I entered google.co.in as the redirect url, and Using the client id and client secret I have successfully created a access token
3. Using this authentication I am able to hit the apis to get Users but unable to get messages
4. Using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages to GET messages but i get the following error:
   {
   "error": {
       "code": "AuthenticatonError",
       "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
       "innerError": {
           "request-id": "e89ce249-f869-4402-8b1f-db547f9d1113",
           "date": "2016-07-19T06:25:45"
       }
   }
   }

Please provide any inputs.

Comment: What permission scopes is the app asking for? to get access to messages you need Mail.Read

Answer (score 0):

> > I entered google.co.in as the redirect url, and Using the client id and client secret I have successfully created a access token

Did you mean that you use the **client credential flow** to request token? The client credential flow is like request below:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant|common}/oauth2/token

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
```

If I understood correctly, the app register by the portal doesn't grant the app-level scope. It grants the delegate scope which we should use the **OAuth 2.0 authorization flow** to request the access token.

Here is the steps for this flow:

1. Use browser to navigate to the link below and login in to get the **authorization code**

   {tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&state=12345
2. Request the token with authorization code

   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com//{tenant}/oauth2/token

   grant_type=authorization_code
   &client_id={clientId}
   &code={authorizationCode}
   &redirect_uri={redirectUrl}
   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
   &client_secret={clientSecret}

More detail about Microsoft Graph app authorization, you can refer to [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization)

Comment: I am able to generate the access token, but i cannot hit the APIs using GET to get message, mailbox, etc. That is when i get the error

Comment: How did you get the token? As I post above there are two ways to get the token.

Comment: You can parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/). Can you share the payload data from your token?

Comment: i used this link in the browser "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.google.co.in&client_id={client_id} and on receiving the authorization code in postman i used POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token    

grant_type=authorization_code&
redirect_uri=https://www.google.co.in&
client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={client_secret}&
code={code}&
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F

Comment: From the error message, it should be relative the incorrect resource you were request. You can check it via parse the token from [here](https://jwt.io/). What's the value of **aud**?

Comment: From postman i am hitting this url to get the messages 
GET:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
HEADER: Authorization: Bearer {Acess Code}
Content type: application/json
RESPONSE: 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticatonError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7afe4e9f-4ddb-4152-965f-8a4474f5f3f7",
            "date": "2016-07-22T08:20:01"
        }
    }
}

Comment: This error is not relative the **postman**. It seems that the parameters you request for the token is incorrect. Have you checked the **aud** property in the access token?

Comment: Using the access token, I am able to hit the APIs for users and drive. Do i need some special rights to access the APIs to acess Mails, contacts,calendar?

Comment: Yes, the app need to grant the `Mail.Read` scope to access the messages. But if you doesn't grant this scope, the error shoule be like `Access is denied. Check credentials and try again`. Can you use this account to login the [Office portal](login.microsoftonline.com) to read the mails manually?

Comment: As per our understanding aud is the redirect URI which i have specified as https://google.co.in  Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: When i log in to my account, i cannot view the mails, contacts, calendar etc objects. Is there any additional setting that needs to be performed in order to view these object.
since we cannot view the object, we are assuming that is the reason we cannot hit the API

Comment: Is it possible you do not have a mailbox configured for this account or there is a mailbox configured but it has never been accessed before? You can check this by logging into https://outlook.office.com with the same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Each API is permissioned under a permission scope to access mail you need Mail.Read, to access calendar you need Calendar.Read, to access contacts you need Contacts.Read and so on. it seems that the auth flow you had was not asking for these scopes and hence the request was getting access denied. For more information about permission scopes: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes